# how to choose tombstone_failure_threshold value if I want to delete billions of entries?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table having approx 15 billions entries and I want to delete approx 13 billions entries from it. I cannot write 13 billion tombstones in one go since there is a disk space crunch.

I am planning to delete data in chunks so I will be creating 400 millions tombstones in one go.

Now, I have 2 questions:

1. What is the optimal value of the `tombstone_failure_threshold` for the above scenario?
2. What is the best way to delete 13 billions entries in my case ?

[EDIT]
Adding schema & queries

```
CREATE TABLE Coupons (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    code text
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '604800', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

- Read query : reading using partition key
- Delete query : deleting using partition key

Comment: show the table schema, what are the queries that are executed against database & how do you plan to delete the data - by primary key, partition key, etc.?

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt for your response. I added schema & queries in description above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading only by using partition key, and not using something that is doing full table scan, like, Spark, then you can just delete the data and don't modify `tombstone_failure_threshold`.

The reason for that is that Cassandra counts tombstones when they are read, for example, if you have partition with multiple rows inside.  But in your case you have one row per partition, so when you read by partition key, you can read at most one tombstone - for given partition.

But the situation is different when you use Spark, DSBulk or custom code that reads many partitions at once - then there are multiple tombstones read, and they are counted against that threshold.